# Modfying methods variable using java parser in java file

Tags: java, methods, javaparser

i am using java parser to read a java file. then i have problem with how to access variable in each method, then modifying the variable name and type in each method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.java");

    CompilationUnit cu;
    try {
        // parse the file
        cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }

    // change the methods names and parameters
    changeMethods(cu);

    // prints the changed compilation unit
    System.out.println(cu.toString());
}

private static void changeMethods(CompilationUnit cu) {
    List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.getTypes();
    for (TypeDeclaration type : types) {
        List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
        for (BodyDeclaration member : members) {
            if (member instanceof MethodDeclaration) {
                // what must i do?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

For more details, i have a method such as below:

```
 private double[] getExtremeValues(double[] d) {    
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;  
    double max = -min;

}
```

in that method, i just want to modify 'double max' with 'double max1'. The second question, how to get 'double[] d' in the method parameter?
Please help! Thanks

Comment: Do you read tutorial available here : https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser ?

Comment: Yeah, but make me confuse to implement with my cases :D

Comment: Please refer to the new manual: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual

The project on google code is some years old, while the new version is being maintained on GitHub since then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to modify all variables contained in a method? In that case you will either need to use recursion or use a visitor (see for example the [GenericVisitorAdapter](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.3.0/com/github/javaparser/ast/visitor/VoidVisitorAdapter.html)).

If instead you want to change just the parameters look at the method "getParameters" in [MethodDeclaration](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.3.0/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/MethodDeclaration.html).

In both cases note that changing just the name of the variable will probably break the code: you need to change also all references to that variable.

What do you mean by changing the type of a method? That can be easily done with the method setType of MethodDeclaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example which modifies the method name. You need to override some methods

```
    private static class MethodNameModifier extends ModifierVisitor<Void> {
        @Override
        public MethodDeclaration visit(MethodDeclaration md, Void arg) {
            super.visit(md, arg);
            //System.out.println(md.getName());
            md.setName("x");
            return md;
        }
    }
```